# Fabric- Android crashes mentioned in Latest Release screen are not displayed in Crashlytics screen

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android, fabric.io

My android application has crashed. Then I login to Fabric (https://fabric.io/login) to see crashes.In the Latest Release screen, it says "Needs Investigation"  and in the Stability section of the screen 5 crashes is reported. Here is the screenshot ;

[image: Fabric ScreenShot]

But when I click on the "Investigate this release issues in Crashlytics" link , crashes are not displayed in the Crashlytics screen. In the "Crashlytics screen "0 crashes" seems in the latest build.

Comment: Sometimes crashes will appear after some time.

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Firebase here. Crashes are sent on relaunch of the app, but we can detect in real-time that the previous session ended in a crash. The Latest Release page will show that a crash occurred before we get the crash from the device. Once the user relaunches the app to send the crash report, then we will display it.

Comment: Hello @Mike But after the crash, I can not relaunch myapp. When I try to open ( click app icon)"Unfortunately it stopped"  message is given.

Comment: Is this a test crash?

Comment: It is not a test crash

Comment: Hmm, the unfortunately it still stopped show up. If you see that after repeated crashes with still no crashes, contact support(at)fabric(dot)io.